# Why is the memory sum of my processes lower than the actual used memory?

Tags: fedora, memory

The sum of all running processes and used memory don't add up. It should be about 10GB used, but it's 33 with swap. What am I missing and where did the memory go?

> top -n1 -b -o "%MEM"

```
top - 14:12:13 up 4 days, 14:34,  1 user,  load average: 2.88, 1.68, 1.40
Tasks: 475 total,   1 running, 473 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
%Cpu(s):  2.7 us,  2.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 94.5 id,  0.0 wa,  0.4 hi,  0.4 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  15720.5 total,    240.2 free,  12496.3 used,   2984.0 buff/cache
MiB Swap:  40960.0 total,  29546.3 free,  11413.7 used.   1585.2 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 420661 aleksan+  20   0 9976208   2.8g   9232 S  53.3  18.0  57:12.01 qemu-sy+
 194572 aleksan+  20   0   14.1g   2.3g   2064 S   0.0  14.9  64:40.09 java
 420783 aleksan+  20   0 4097980 856672  62712 S   0.0   5.3   6:51.14 Isolate+
 422028 aleksan+  20   0  267.5g 599920 178416 S   0.0   3.7   6:08.70 Rider.B+
 434079 aleksan+  20   0 3192940 412608  96276 S   0.0   2.6   0:33.46 Isolate+
 407972 aleksan+  20   0 8830056 385000 120472 S   0.0   2.4  11:59.39 firefox
 179359 aleksan+  20   0 1129.1g 261820  60924 S   0.0   1.6  38:42.86 slack
```

> free -g

```
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:              15          12           0           1           2           1
Swap:             39          11          28
```

> df -h

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /dev
tmpfs           7.7G   39M  7.7G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           3.1G  2.6M  3.1G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p4  444G  166G  276G  38% /
tmpfs           7.7G   15M  7.7G   1% /tmp
/dev/nvme0n1p4  444G  166G  276G  38% /home
/dev/nvme0n1p2  974M  273M  634M  31% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p1  599M   29M  571M   5% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1.6G  716K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/nvme0n1p4  444G  166G  276G  38% /run/timeshift/backup
```

> cat /proc/meminfo

```
MemTotal:       16097796 kB
MemFree:          175784 kB
MemAvailable:    1247900 kB
Buffers:              56 kB
Cached:          2442848 kB
SwapCached:      1709900 kB
Active:          6085628 kB
Inactive:        6024496 kB
Active(anon):    5282164 kB
Inactive(anon):  5705444 kB
Active(file):     803464 kB
Inactive(file):   319052 kB
Unevictable:       65308 kB
Mlocked:            5908 kB
SwapTotal:      41943032 kB
SwapFree:       30263284 kB
Zswap:                 0 kB
Zswapped:              0 kB
Dirty:              2044 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       9666652 kB
Mapped:           681552 kB
Shmem:           1315408 kB
KReclaimable:     291168 kB
Slab:             615504 kB
SReclaimable:     291168 kB
SUnreclaim:       324336 kB
KernelStack:       41520 kB
PageTables:       120196 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    49991928 kB
Committed_AS:   34806112 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      127080 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
Percpu:            20416 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:    161792 kB
ShmemHugePages:   192512 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
FileHugePages:         0 kB
FilePmdMapped:         0 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
Hugetlb:               0 kB
DirectMap4k:      332800 kB
DirectMap2M:     9873408 kB
DirectMap1G:     6291456 kB
```

Comment: You've only shown 7 most memory hungry applications, there must be more. What if you have ten thousand threads each eating a couple of megs of RAM? Lastly, it could be GPU drivers leaking RAM.

Comment: it's not impossible, but it's not true. I didn't post whole output, because hundred entries with 0.0% wouldn't add much value. How can I check GPU ram usage? I have Intel integrated graphics.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/482795/can-i-see-the-amount-of-memory-which-is-allocated-as-gem-buffers