# What shared memory is not controlled by SHMAX/SHMALL?

Tags: linux-kernel, shared-memory

We are debugging a situation where the cached/shared memory increase and increase until the system reach OOM-killer.

We have set shmax and shmall in sysctl.conf but without any visible effect. Do we need to enable something more for shmax/shmall to work? Or can some part of the system go beyond this limit, how hard is it enforced? Can buggy user space application or only bugs in kernel/drivers cause it? The application that we debug use graphics and video decoding. Can drivers go beyond the max limits?

```
kernel.shmmax = 2147483648
kernel.shmall = 524288
```

Linux kernel is 5.15.71(from Yocto meta-intel). Our system has 4GB ram and no swap (we tried to enable swap but it did not help with the stability of the system). We use Wayland/weston but not systemd. We set the value in sysctl.conf and reboot for it to take effect. We also confirmed the values with ipcs. We tried to set the shared memory to max 2 GB.

```
ipcs -l
------ Shared Memory Limits --------
max number of segments = 4096
max seg size (kbytes) = 2097152
max total shared memory (kbytes) = 2097152
min seg size (bytes) = 1
```

Here is some example output from free, meminfo, smem, etc a few minutes before it reaches OOM.

```
free -w                                                                    
               total        used        free      shared     buffers       cache   available
Mem:         3844036      479428      263444     2711864       11324     3089840      585716
Swap:              0           0           0                                  

#### cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        3844036 kB
MemFree:          262680 kB
MemAvailable:     584940 kB
Buffers:           11324 kB
Cached:          3055620 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:            98764 kB
Inactive:         645792 kB
Active(anon):        732 kB
Inactive(anon):   394288 kB
Active(file):      98032 kB
Inactive(file):   251504 kB
Unevictable:     2708620 kB
Mlocked:             100 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:                12 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        386388 kB
Mapped:           162732 kB
Shmem:           2711864 kB
KReclaimable:      34208 kB
Slab:              68656 kB
SReclaimable:      34208 kB
SUnreclaim:        34448 kB
KernelStack:        4640 kB
PageTables:         5904 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     1922016 kB
Committed_AS:    4068728 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:       15104 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
Percpu:             1040 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
Hugetlb:               0 kB
DirectMap4k:       72236 kB
DirectMap2M:     3938304 kB
DirectMap1G:     2097152 kB



#### smem                                                                     
  PID User     Command                         Swap      USS      PSS      RSS  
 …..
 1306 weston   /usr/libexec/wpe-webkit-1.1        0    27192    51419    98928  
 1379 weston   /usr/libexec/wpe-webkit-1.1        0   190268   214958   266040  

Area                           Used      Cache   Noncache                       
firmware/hardware                 0          0          0                     
kernel image                      0          0          0                       
kernel dynamic memory       3030848    2938432      92416                     
userspace memory             555656     162732     392924                     
free memory                  257532     257532          0

Map                                       PIDs   AVGPSS      PSS              
……
/usr/lib/libcrypto.so.3                     20      527    10544                
/usr/lib/dri/iris_dri.so                     5     2196    10982              
/usr/lib/dri/iHD_drv_video.so                1    20356    20356              
/usr/lib/libWPEWebKit-1.1.so.0.2.6           5    14539    72697              
[heap]                                      45     2060    92700              
<anonymous>                                 45     5970   268688
```

Edit: Added df info for tmpfs. The tmpfs mounts showed with df does not show any extra ordinary size increase.

```
/# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       9.8G  1.9G  7.4G  21% /
devtmpfs        1.9G  2.1M  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.9G  636K  1.9G   1% /run
tmpfs           751M  5.8M  745M   1% /var/volatile
tmpfs            40K     0   40K   0% /mnt/.psplash
```

Comment: `SwapTotal:             0 kB`?  If you *need* reliability, disable memory overcommit, disable the [out-of-fuel](https://lwn.net/Articles/104185/), err, OOM killer, and provide your system with enough swap so it can run **reliably**.

Comment: I tested to add 16GB of swap, it delayed the crash with a few hours but did not make the system stable. But I have trouble see what is using now close to 20GB of memory...Things seems to be cleared/swapped. Here are some values when it was 2-3GB left of swap: MemTotal:    3844024 kB
MemFree:     108624 kB
MemAvailable:     173040 kB
Cached:          3356196 kB
SwapCached:        30340 kB
Active:           339312 kB
Inactive:        3124336 kB
Active(anon):     294284 kB
Inactive(anon):  3121236 kB
SwapTotal:      16777212 kB
SwapFree:        2978812 kB
Shmem:           3303908 kB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SHMAX and SHMALL won't constraint the size of your miscellaneous [tmpfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.10/filesystems/tmpfs.html).

> Since tmpfs lives completely in the page cache and on swap, all tmpfs
> pages will be shown as “Shmem” in /proc/meminfo and “Shared” in
> free(1).

Check with the `df` utility how many of these filesystem are actually mounted on your system and eventually limit their maximum possible size thanks to the `size=` parameter of corresponding mount operation.

Of course if your application uses this kind of filesystem and no swap space is made available, the application might well block or stop processing because it won't find any space left on device.

Comment: We looked into tmpfs and could not see any increase in usage. The size is large but usage is always very small. Is tmpfs the only shared/cached memory not affected by shmax/shmall?

Comment: Yes indeed : GEM buffers. cf accepted answer as part of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/482795/can-i-see-the-amount-of-memory-which-is-allocated-as-gem-buffers

Comment: Without swap, we see that gem objects increase until OOM. With swap, just before OOM it clear/swap out. i915_gem_objects in debugfs goes down alot at that point. But then something else eat up all swap at it still reach OOM. I don't see anything about limiting gem in that answer thread.

Comment: Oh come on ! Your question was : "What shared memory is not controlled by SHMAX/SHMALL". Then I answer : tmpfs and GEM buffers. I just gave the link in order to justify my statement regarding GEM buffers. If you are now looking for a way to limit GEM buffers then it is IMHO another question.

Comment: I think what I wanted to know was a complete (or near complete) list of things that was outside of shamax/shmall control. And if so how to control them. tmpfs seems to be easy to set a max limit on, but gem seems to be able to do what ever it wants... But I will take this as a learning input on writing clear questions and accept this answer.